# Cassandra without replication

Tags: cassandra, distributed, database, nosql

Is there a way to configure a Cassandra cluster with data centre splitting / NetworkTopologyStrategy / ReplicationFactor 1?  Basically, I want to keep the data in its originating node but still be able to query it all from any node.  The business use case is:

I have a group of customers, each is a different firm with data in their own datacentres.  I want to do some cross-firm data analysis without *useable* data leaving their premises i.e. I can't get them all to load their data onto a central server.  I am looking for a platform that allows me to deploy software to each firm such that I can do distributed comparisons of their data without them having to send me their data in bulk (much of it is prohibited for distribution).  Data transferred in a non-readable wire format as part of a distributed "join" will be fine as long as I'm not replicating the data to the other customers data centres.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a replication factor of 1. However, ensuring that each item of data is on the node at a particular site requires additional work.  You will need to have a customer ID as the partition key for every table, and write a custom partitioner that maps customer ID to a token for that customer.  And you will have to manually configure each node to use only the one token for its customer.

Comment: Thanks Raedwald.  The data customer ID as the PK so that won't be a problem.  I am now planning to have each customer load their data into non-replicated tables.  Then I will obfuscate the data and load into tables that are replicated.  Then I can run analysis centrally on data that is not exposed and send back to each customer where they can join it back with their originating data.  So in summary, I need a set of tables that are nor replicated and a set that are.  Can I do this with different tables spaces or do I need to have two different clusters to support this?

Comment: @Robin if you have a second question, ask it as a second question.